# Redundant Database Query using JWTAuth and Laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt

When using [JWTAuth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth), every *signed* request sent to the API performs a database query retrieving the user, i.e.:

```
select * from `users` where `id` = '1' limit 1
```

For most of my routes, this query is redundant and I would like to remove it. In [this](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/pull/464) pull request, there is a discussion about this topic. Although, I am already using a custom middleware, but I suppose the one supplied by JWTAuth is still there.

How do I remove the redundant user DB query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middleware that was causing this behavior was *ThrottleRequests*, more explicitly `resolveMaxAttempts()` and `resolveRequestSignature()` in  *\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests*. Both these functions are performing `$request->user()`.

This was inherited by the `protected $middlewareGroups` which contains the default *api* middleware group:

```
'api' => [
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can read from the comments on that pull you referenced, you must create your custom middleware and check if the token is valid with `check` function, this means you will also need to manually authenticate the user when he signs to your application

> By using check() and checkOrFail()
>
> Yes I would definitely recommend adding your own middleware.

So you will need to manually `Authenticate` and `check` for the token validity if you don't want to query the database unnecessarily.

Comment: As I wrote, I do have a custom middleware, but the query is still being fired.

Comment: Can you include your code from your middleware then, and also include your `api.php`

Comment: The `api.php` file just contains routes, like: `Route::post('/search', 'SearchController@index');`. And for that route, I am not using any middlewares except for the default `api` middleware supplied by `RouteServiceProvider.api`.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `sql` is being fired after your `middleware` executes, or somewhere else in the `controller`?

Comment: I am using Laravel Debugbar which is indicating that a query is being fired. It doesn't say exactly when.

Comment: Try using `dd` just before your `return $request($next);` in your middleware, if the debugbar shows that query after that, then your query is executing in middleware and you are doing something wrong, if it doesn't then it is being fired from somewhere else

Comment: If i send a request to this route, it also makes the query: `Route::get('/test', function() {
    return [];
});`

Comment: I don't follow, what you wanted to say?

Comment: If i send a request to /test like this: `axios.get('/api/test');` the DB query fetching the user is still being executed. The route is just returning an empty array. 

So, is JWTAuth hooking into the `api` middleware?

Comment: I can't tell since I don't see your `api.php` code, but I don't think so

Comment: I figured it out. Posted a solution below.